# Change font size in SSRS dynamically

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In my report, am just trying to change the font size of the text box dynamically depending upon the length. My expression is,

```
=iif(Len(Parameters!CandidateName) < 27, "30pt","25pt")
```

here, if the length is > 27 it is displaying `25pt` and if it is < 27 it is diplaying `30pt`, and the size is not changing. Can anyone help me here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Evaluate length of the `Value` of the `CandidateName` parameter:

```
=iif(Len(Parameters!CandidateName.Value) < 27, "30pt","25pt")
```

For further reading, here is a [reference for the `Parameters` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255264.aspx).